# React Native Admob Plugin - Build fails with latest React Native

Tags: react-native

```
D:\projects\fortuna\node_modules\react-native-admob\android\src\main\java\com\sbugert\rnadmob\RNAdMobRewardedVideoAdModule.java:89: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
@Override
^
```

1 error
:react-native-admob:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':react-native-admob:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac'.

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is correct with old react versions. With latest version you should put this code in admob android build.gradle file: **\node_modules\react-native-admob\android\build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be a 
    @Override

in line 89 of 
RNAdMobRewardedVideoAdModule.java file.
Delete it and you should be good to go.